# Hamcrest or assertj : test element in list with requirements

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest, assertj

using hamcrest and java 8, what's the easiest way (one liner) to assert that a collection contains a element with a specific set of requirements?
I'd like to be able to retrieve the element, if it exists, and perform some tests on it, in one go (and in a readable form).
Or maybe at least assert that a list contains a specific element, and return it in one go, so that I can then perform some tests on it.

Answer (score 2):

With AssertJ I would try one of these:

- [`anySatisfy`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anySatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-) (takes a `Consumer` to express the requirements ending with informative errors)
- [`anyMatch`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) (takes a `Predicate`, error is less informative)
- [`hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying-java.util.function.Consumer-) (takes a `Consumer`, work iif exactly one element matches)
- [`haveAtLeastOne`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#haveAtLeastOne-org.assertj.core.api.Condition-) (takes a `Condition` which is a like an Hamcrest macther)

To get a one liner, it is likely that you will have to extract the `Condition`, `Consumer` or `Predicate` to a variable/field instead of inlining it.

Follow the javadoc links, they all have code examples showing how to they can be used. You can also have a look at the [assertj-examples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/tree/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples) project, a showcase of AssertJ.

Hope that helps